# Center of $\mathrm{PGL}_n( \mathbb{K} )$

Tags: group-theory, projective-space

I want to know how $Z(\mathrm{PGL}_n( \mathbb{K} )) = \left\{ \overline{I_n} \right\} $ and there is a proof that I don't understand. The proof is the following \begin{align*}
& \overline{A} \in Z(\mathrm{PGL}_n( \mathbb{K} )) \\
\Leftrightarrow & \forall \overline{B} \in \mathrm{PGL}_n( \mathbb{K} ) \mbox{, } \overline{AB} = \overline{BA}\\
\Leftrightarrow & \exists \lambda_B \neq 0 \mbox{, } AB = \lambda_B BA \\
\Leftrightarrow & A \in Z( \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{K}) ) = \mathbb{K}^* I_n = \overline{I_n}\\ \Leftrightarrow & \overline{A} = \overline{I_n} \\
\end{align*}

But I don't understand the second fact : $\forall \overline{B} \in \mathrm{PGL}_n( \mathbb{K} ) \mbox{, } \overline{AB} = \overline{BA} \Leftrightarrow \exists \lambda_B \neq 0 \mbox{, } AB = \lambda_B BA \\$. I tried to compute $\overline{AB} = \overline{BA}$ in many ways but I don't get the result. Is there somebody to give me an indication ? Thank you

Comment: By definition of $\mathrm{PGL}_n$, two elements are eqaual $\overline{X} = \overline{Y}$ exactly when they differ by a non-zero scalar: $Y = \lambda X$ for some $\lambda$. Now just apply this to $X = AB$ and $Y = BA$.

Comment: Maybe it helps to let $n=2$ and explicitly write down when $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is such that $\overline A\in Z(PGL_2)$. Taking $B=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\&1\end{pmatrix}$ for each $\alpha\in K^\times$ suffices.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forget this fact @Nick

Comment: And yes, what you said @Kenta S is also true. Thank you so much

Comment: @KentaS, I think that [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589294/center-of-mathrmpgl-n-mathbbk#comment9663164_4589294) suggestion (for which $B$ to test) will only allow one to conclude that $A$ is diagonal, not that $A$ is scalar (hence trivial in $\operatorname{PGL}_2$).  Even that doesn't work if $\mathbb K$ (which you call $K$) is $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: Right, then you can check $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @KentaS, [right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589294/center-of-mathrmpgl-n-mathbbk#comment9663212_4589294).  If $\mathbb K$ is $\mathbb F_2$, then you must also check an order-$3$ element, like $\begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.